# jQuery Multiselect checkboxes don't appear

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the following asp.net user control (below), where I'm trying to implement the jQuery, Multiselect checkboxes feature.  Unfortunately I'm doing something wrong, as I'm only getting a listbox of four values without the checkboxes.

After downloading these jQuery libraries and style sheets, I then added them to my project in Visual Studio2013, after which I drag them to the .ASCX file, so I'm pretty sure they are pointing to the right files.  I've tried with older versions of jQuery and that didn't make any difference.  This user control is part of a form in a Master page web configuration.  We're on Dot-Net 4.0.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DateStoreSelector.ascx.cs" Inherits="OfficeIntranet.Controls.Warehouse.DateStoreSelector" %>

<link href="../../Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Forms/../Styles/SOTracking.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Styles/bootstrap-3.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Styles/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap-3.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=lstStores]').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:Panel runat="server" >
    <div id="itDiv" style="padding: 5px; height: 220px; width: 171px; float: left; border: 1px solid black">
        <%# Eval("FormatedDate")%>
        <hr style="border-top: 1px solid"/>
        <div runat="server">
            <%# Eval("theData")%>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:ListBox ID="lstStores" Width="70px" Height="104px" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="01" Value="01"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="15" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="24" Value="24"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="37" Value="37"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Update" Width="125px" Height="25px" ID="selectStores" OnClick="selectStores_OnClick" ></asp:Button> 
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here and why the checkboxes don't appear?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the order with which you're loading the scripts.

Move

`<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

*before* the

`<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap-3.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

and you should be good to go.

If this doesn't work, check how you're targeting the listbox `ID` attribute.

Instead of

`$('[id*=lstStores]')`

it should be

`$("select[id$='lstStores']")`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however, that didn't seem to help.

Comment: I've tried:  'code' <br>$("select[id$='lstStores']").multiselect({ ...   and I've tried:  <br>  $('id$=lstStores]').multiselect({ ...  and I've tried:  <br>  $("select[id$=lstStores]").multiselect({ ...      <br> Very frustrating.

Comment: I also just tried:                                                                                 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#lstStores').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: @Craig can you post the rendered html of the ListBox please?

Comment: I have to look at the rendered ListBox in Chrome Developer Tools.  And then, I can't cut and paste more than one line at a time.  I've tried holding down every key possible (well, almost) and can't seem to cut and paste more than one line.    
    $(function() {
        $("select[id$='lstStores']").multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });

Answer (score 0):

Your ListBox is a ASP.NET controller with runat="server" so i think you should remplace your :

```
$('[id*=lstStores]')
```

By :

```
$("#<%= lstStores.ClientID %>")
```

**EDIT :**
I think it's your path of all your js that are wrong because i tested your code with this links :

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And that works.

Comment: I tried:                                                                                                <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%= lstStores.ClientID %>").multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>                                                                                                                                                                                                                     No change?

Comment: I've commented out my javascript and stylesheets;  then I cut and pasted yours in, along with your suggestion of the ClientID above and still the same results.  It wouldn't matter that this 'control' is the 'ItemTemplate' in a 'ListView' object, would it?